# How to call a specific class in any app from notification?

Tags: iphone

in my app, i have generated a local notification. when the notification will appear it starts the app from beginning, but i want to go a specific class, not in app delegate and view controller classes. MAy i code in the methods like **application will enter foreground** delegates in app delegate class. or somewhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no "app delegate class".  It is a protocol that any class may agree to honor.  Oftentimes it is a subclass of UIApplication, but you can make it any class you like, so long as you agree to support the ApplicationDelegateProtocol.

Nevertheless, your localNotifications will be delivered there, either via the front door on activation, or through the didReceiveLocalNotification: method.  From there you can call any method in any object that you like.  If you need specifics as to where to dispatch it, you can include a dictionary in the notification's userInfo property.

edit:  My mistake.  The name of the protocol is UIApplicationDelegate.

Comment: Thx for response. But where i will get notifications user info property.

Comment: NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

Comment: and you can read the localNotif.userInfo property when you get the notification back.